# Jquery - Selecting div after style change

Tags: jquery, function, timeout

I have a select box that triggers a onchange event (not by my code, but by a plugin's code).
That select box will hide/show the next box according to the item selected. The way this plugin hides or shows the next box is by changing the style of the element.

For instance:

If I select option 1. The plugin triggers the onchange event and changes the next box's style from

```
display:none
```

to

```
display:list-item
```

Once the item style changes, I need to select that item and do other stuff to it with my own code. The problem is that my onchange is triggering before the plugin's code, so it can't find any item to select.

My code:

```
("#input").change(function(){

var mymatch = $("li[style='display: list-item;']");});
```

if I were to reselect again option 1, this would work, because the plugins function has already executed once.

I tried adding a setTimeout to my function, but that did not work.
So I guess my function needs to either listen for style changes, or somehow execute after the plugin function... any ideas? Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: try adding your js file after the plugin's js

Comment: Not a bad idea. I need to see if I have control over that.

Comment: Also I don't think using the style attribute as your selector is the best bet, if you want to get all the li's that are visible you can just use `$('li:visible')`

Comment: $('li:visible') solves my problem. Thanks koala_dev. You can post this as the answer if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try going for a more concise selector instead of the style attribute, if you're looking for visible list items you can use

```
$('li:visible')
```